# Return tuple that preserves references but copies r-values

Tags: c++, tuples, idioms, rvalue

I need to make a lambda that returns a tuple to be used for sorting a vector of objects.  The tuple gathers a collection of attributes from the object.  Some attributes are references to large objects that should not be copied (`f()` in the code below), others are small r-values (`g()` in the code below).  What is the simplest or most idiomatic way of writing the lambda?

```
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <algorithm>

struct A {
    std::vector<int> const &f() const;
    int g() const;
};

void example() {
    auto sort_key = [](A const &a) {
        //return std::tuple{a.f(), a.g()}; // copies the vector from f()
        //return std::tie(a.f(), a.g()); // can't bind the int from g()
        //return std::forward_as_tuple(a.f(), a.g()); // returns a reference to the int from g(), which expires when this function returns
        return std::tuple<std::vector<int> const &, int>{a.f(), a.g()}; // works, but requires specifying the types
    };

    std::vector<A> v;
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [&](A const &a, A const &b) {
        return sort_key(a) < sort_key(b);
    });
}
```

I'm embarrassed to say forward_as_tuple was my first attempt, and after a long debug session I realized it was returning int&& for the second attribute, a value that goes out of scope.  Writing it this way was muscle memory because `forward_as_tuple(...) < forward_as_tuple(...)` is perfectly fine by my understanding: since everything is all on one line of code we will have lifetime extension for all the references.

Explicitly specifying the types - reference for first attribute, value for second - when constructing the tuple works, and that's what I'm doing now, but I'd prefer something cleaner.  (Okay, truth be told it's not so bad, but I'm asking because I'm curious if there's something better.)

I could probably work up a helper function, call it forward_references_but_copy_rvalues, but is there something already in the standard library that could do this?